# My App Closes on a button click

Tags: java, android

> **Help Me Please to find the error**
>
> Please when i click the button my application close

**emp.XML**

```
**XML file*

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/lawa"
        tools:context="com.example.johnwalls.projet.Main2Activity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="10dp"

            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffffff"
            android:phoneNumber="false"
            android:text=""
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"

            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pass" />
        android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="10dp"

            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffffff"
            android:phoneNumber="false"
            android:text=""
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/log" />
        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="105.0dp"
            android:layout_height="40.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/log"

            android:background="@drawable/log"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:onClick=""
            />



        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="105.0dp"
            android:layout_height="40.0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ins"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:onClick="goButtonClicked"
            android:id="@+id/goButton"

            />



    </RelativeLayout>`
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.emp);
        }



        public void goButtonClicked(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,SaveadminActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
```

**SaveadminActivity**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class SaveadminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.enregistreradmin);
    }
}


        [enter image description here][1]
```

What are you trying to achieve
what are you expecting to get out
What did you get out (include error messages)
What else have you tried?
What do you think is causing it?
Why do you need to make a new question for it? Why is your problem different to other, similar questions on here?

Comment: Please fix your post including formatting and taking out the nonsense

Comment: Please add your code from SaveadminActivity

Comment: Okay and the Stacktrace would be useful too, you find it under logcat, just scroll to the bottom after the error occurs :)

Comment: julien-100000 , sorry i don't understand you :(

Comment: Okay, no Problem. How to you start your app, with Android Studio and an Emulator?

Comment: i run with my mobile

Comment: Okay, so you connected your device with android studio?

Comment: yes  connected with Android Studio

Comment: Okay in the Bottom of Android Studio there is a tab "Logcat". Switch to that tab and scroll down to the bottom, right after your App crashed. There should be a red error message which you then can add to the question

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method goButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'goButton'

Comment: i have goButtonClicked(View) methode in Main2Activity :(

Comment: Okay then please add the full xml where your button you want to click is in and not just the Button, because in the layout file you posted there is an other button :)

Comment: Your stack trace most likely has chained exceptions....and one that reads "ActivityNotFoundException"....post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @johnwalls I have posted an answer. Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can solve the issue

**emp.XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/lawa"
        tools:context="com.example.johnwalls.projet.Main2Activity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="10dp"

            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffffff"
            android:phoneNumber="false"
            android:text=""
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"

            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pass" />
        android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="10dp"

            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffffff"
            android:phoneNumber="false"
            android:text=""
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/log"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/log" />
        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="105.0dp"
            android:layout_height="40.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/log"

            android:background="@drawable/log"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            />



        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="105.0dp"
            android:layout_height="40.0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ins"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/goButton"

            />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

       Button goButton;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.emp);
            goButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
            goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,SaveadminActivity.class);
            startActivity(i); 
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Main2Activity delete goButton method and add to onCreate this

```
goButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,SaveadminActivity.class);
        startActivity(i); 
            }
        });
```

Main2Activity will looks like this

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

       Button goButton;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.emp);
            goButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
            goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,SaveadminActivity.class);
            startActivity(i); 
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: This only will not solve the problem as he has to delete this line `android:onClick="goButtonClicked"` from the `emp.XML`

Comment: true, didn't notice this